# Workaround to fix StreamListener constant Channel Name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am using cloud stream to consuming messages I am using something like

```
 @StreamListener(target = "CONSTANT_CHANNEL_NAME")
  public void readingData(String input){
    System.out.println("consumed info is"+input);
  }
```

But I want to keep channel name as per my environment and it should be picked from property file, while as per Spring channel name should be constant.

Is there any work around to fix this problem?

Edit:1
Let's see the actual situation

1. I am using multiple queues and dlq queues and it's binding is done with rabbit-mq
2. I want to change my channel name and queue name as per my environment
3. I want to do all on same AMQP host.

My Sink Code

```
public interfaceProcessorSink extends Sink {

    @Input(CONSTANT_CHANNEL_NAME)
    SubscribableChannel channel();

    @Input(CONSTANT_CHANNEL_NAME_1)
    SubscribableChannel channel2();

    @Input(CONSTANT_CHANNEL_NAME_2)
    SubscribableChannel channle2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick target value from property file as below:

```
@StreamListener(target = "${streamListener.target}")
  public void readingData(String input){
    System.out.println("consumed info is"+input);
  }
```

application.yml

```
streamListener:
      target:  CONSTANT_CHANNEL_NAME
```

Comment: Consider defining a bean named '${streamListener.target}' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to do that I wonder why do you even care? In fact if anything you ***do want to make it constant*** so it is always the same, but thru configuration properties map it to different remote destinations (e.g., Kafka, Rabbit etc). For example `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=myKafkaTopic` states that channel by the name `input` will be mapped to (bridged with) Kafka topic named `myKafkaTopic`'. 
In fact, to further prove my point we completely abstracted away channels all together for users who use spring-cloud-function programming model, but that is a whole different discussion.

My point is that I believe you are actually creating a problem rather the solving it since with externalisation of the channel name you create probably that due to misconfiguration your actual bound channel and the channel you're mentioning in your properties are not going to be the same.

Comment: Let's understand situation
1. I am using multiple queues and dlq queues and it's binding is done with rabbit-mq
2. I want to change my channel name and queue name as per my environment
3. I want to do all on same AMQP host.

Comment: Once again, you are missing my point. The ***channel*** is an artefact of Spring Messaging, The AMQP ***destination*** is (in your case I assume) the artefact of RabbitMQ. Spring Cloud Stream framework provides capabilities to map/re-map _destination_ to _channels_ allowing the same channel to actually represent different destination (based on the environment or any other reason).